Gradle 8.0 is not useable with Flutter 3.7
[   +2 ms] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[   +4 ms] * Where:
[   +1 ms] Script 'C:\Users\hp\OneDrive\Documents\flutter_windows_2.10.1-stable\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 912
[        ] * What went wrong:
[        ] A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
[        ] > A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
[        ]    > Could not create task ':app:packLibsflutterBuildDebug'.
[        ]       > No signature of method: org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.Jar.destinationDir() is applicable for argument types: (File) values:[D:\WORK\mobile\build\app\intermediates\flutter\debug]

We all should be able to use the latest build system, gradle 8.0 without any errors, sooner or later it will be required, please notice I didn't provide the full result or the full log error of gradle,

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

The PR https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/121958 should fix Gradle 8 incompatiblities, fixing the issue https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/112858.
That PR is included in 3.10.0, so yes, 3.7 is not compatible with Gradle 8.
Besides that, your error suggest you are using Flutter 2.10.1.
